# Passing a date string into a function using pandas read_gbq is not recognized

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

Hello and thanks for taking the time to read....
The date string(i.e., date_start) appears to have been passed successfully into the function based on the two print functions' output(follows the code below) but it is not recognized as a date in the where clause since the result set is null (result set is not null outside of the function when using the hard-coded date string literals.

```
date_start = '2016-10-14 09:00:00'
    def get_recs_w_date_range(date_l):
      "Iterate through various date ranges to create the a timeframe sample for later aggregation"
    global df1
    global date_g
    date_g = date_l
    df1 = pd.read_gbq("select Timestamp, bytes, dst_addr, cast(dst_port as integer) as dst_port, \
    cast(duration_ms as integer) as duration_ms, protocol, flow_direction \
    FROM ipfix.ipfix \
     where Timestamp between timestamp('date_l') and timestamp('2016-10-14 09:00:30') limit 50",
              project_id="network-sec-analytics")
    print('The value of local var date_l is: {}'.format(date_l))
return

get_recs_w_date_range(date_start) 

print('The value of global var date_g is: {}'.format(date_g))

df1

    The value of local var date_l is: 2016-10-14 09:00:00
    The value of global var date_g is: 2016-10-14 09:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think it is an easy enough fix. You need to impute the value of `date_l` to your query, which you are not doing. Try this:

```
def get_recs_w_date_range(date_l):
    """Iterate through various date ranges to create the a timeframe sample for later aggregation"""
    query = """SELECT Timestamp, bytes, dst_addr,
                 cast(dst_port as integer) as dst_port,
                 cast(duration_ms as integer) as duration_ms,
                 protocol, flow_direction 
               FROM ipfix.ipfix
               WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN timestamp('{}') AND
                 timestamp('2016-10-14 09:00:30')
               LIMIT 50""".format(date_l)
    return pd.read_gbq(query, project_id="network-sec-analytics")
```

The `format` method will replace the `{}` with the value of `date_l`. Your query should work now.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Kartik... very helpful.  Seems as though there may be a formatting issue with the date string. I added this initialization: date_start = '2016-10-14 09:00:00' and then called the function with get_recs_w_date_range(date_start). I am getting this error:  GenericGBQException: Reason: invalidQuery, Message: Encountered " <ID> "09:00:00 "" at line 0, column 0.
Was expecting:
    ")" ...

Comment: Seems like a quoting problem. Enclose the `{}` in single quotes and try. Essentially: `... BETWEEN timestamp('{}') AND...`

Comment: Yes, you are correct sir !  Thanks so much for your help here Kartik and Go Terps !!

Comment: Hahaha! Go Terps! I made the change in the answer as well to reflect the quotation.